# Usando dois arquivos JSON com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Bom dia/tarde/noite, estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade tentando colocar 2 arquivos JSON e comparar uma chave, por exemplo, no primeiro arquivo vai ter varios endereços e uma chave relacionando eles, essa chave eu coloquei como "chave": 1, e no segundo arquivo vai ter uma tabela, na qual ele vai comparar e se a chave for a mesma, ele vai exibir alguns dos dados dessa tabela, e se for outra chave, da tabela seguinte, e por ai vai, esse codigo que estou usando foi copiado de um lugar e feita varias modificações por mim, copiei o original pra ter uma base, segue o codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var map;
  var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.2146027, -45.8854213);
  var zoomLevel = 12;
  var mapOptions = {
    center: centerPos,
    zoom: zoomLevel
  }; //DEFININDO A POSICAO INICIAL DO MAPA        

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2whwa", function(data) { //BUSCANDO OS DADOS NO MYJSON

    $.each(data, function(i) {

      var tipo = 'TURBIDEZ';

      var image = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VCarnaval/IHC/master/newProject/images/car_red.png';

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //CRIANDO OS MARCADORES NO MAPA
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.long),
        title: this.bairro + "\n" + tipo + "\nAmostras Realizadas: " + this.jan.turbidez[0] + "\nAmostras em conformidade com padrão: " + this.jan.turbidez[1],
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Agradeço desde ja

Comment: Só estou vendo uma chamada de JSON nesse código. Qual é o endereço do outro JSON e qual atributo você quer comparar?